# Business Rule Engine Implementation using Drools

Tags: xml, drools, rule-engine, business-rules, drools-kie-server

I am working for an enterprise banking project. I was recently given a requirement to validate an XML coming from various banks. I have to build an application that allows the definition of Business Rules and then apply those rules to incoming messages (in this case XML ). The team has given me the freedom to choose any product I like and I know that drool will be best for it.

As drools' beginner, I had seen various tutorial and understood the basic. But I am still confused how to use them in this project. I am also not able to get good resources on drool banking specific drool example for Rules Definition and Validation.

Seeing the drools example I got to know that it uses POJO's on which I can add the business rules. How can I use it with XML? Do I need to POJO from the XML or drool can directly work with XML?

Can anyone tell me how can I proceed further ?

Comment: If the messages adhere to an XML schema and if the XML schema is not too fancy, use JAXB, the Java Architecture for XML Binding.